# Many to Many Relationship EF

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I've got two entity objects:

```
   public class Contact
    {
        public int ContactID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Friend> Friends { get; set; }

    }
```

and Friend:

```
public class Friend
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ContactId1 { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ContactId2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

where ContactId1 maps back to a ContactID and ContactId2 maps back to another ContactId.

How do I go about making sure the is generated with the proper relationships?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Many-To-Many Relationship in Code-First EF4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148844/many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first-ef4)

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend your `Friend` class:

```
public class Friend
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("Contact1")]
    public int ContactId1 { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact1 { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Contact2")]
    public int ContactId2 { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact2 { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

And add an attribute to the `Friends` collection in `Contact`:

```
[InverseProperty("Contact1")]
public ICollection<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
```

(You can also use Fluent API instead of annotations.)

The result are two one-to-many relationships (you can't map this model as many-to-many). The first is between `Contact.Friends` and `Friend.Contact1` and the second has `Friend.Contact2` as one endpoint. The endpoint in `Friend` is not exposed in the model.

You can then query for example for all friend contacts of a given contact created before today:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
IEnumerable<Contact> friendContacts = context.Contacts
    .Where(c => c.ContactId == givenId)
    .Select(c => c.Friends
        .Where(f => f.DateCreated < today)
        .Select(f => f.Contact2))
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

**Eit**

The mapping above doesn't work because `Friend` has two required relationships to `Contact`. By default for required one-to-many relationships EF will enable cascading delete which is not allowed for two relationships at the same time. We need to rewrite the mapping with Fluent API to disable cascading delete because this is not possible with data annotations:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
}

public class Friend
{
    public int ContactID1 { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact1 { get; set; }

    public int ContactID2 { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact2 { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Then override `OnModelCreating` in your derived context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Friend>()
        .HasKey(f => new { f.ContactID1, f.ContactID2 });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Friend>()
        .HasRequired(f => f.Contact1)
        .WithMany(c => c.Friends)
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.ContactID1);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Friend>()
        .HasRequired(f => f.Contact2)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.ContactID2)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);  // <- Important
}
```

Comment: Thanks Slauma-- but I'm getting an error when running my application--Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The database creation succeeded, but the creation of the database objects did not. See inner exception for more details. ---> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The referential rel
ationship will result in a cyclical reference that is not allowed. [ Constraint name = Contact_Friends ].. thoughts?

Comment: @ek_ny: See my Edit above. I'm not sure if it will solve the problem, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want two rows of friend referring two on contact, right ? If yes you need two create to instances of friend. The Entity Framework Code First does, by default, recognize the 
key relationships by the name of your property. So in your Friend class the property should
names ContactId because the entity is names Contact.

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Friend> Friends { get; set; }

}

public class Friend
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

## Edit

If you want a friend have many contact you need a relation table.

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Friend> Friends { get; set; }

}

public class Friend
{
    public int FriendId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}

public class FriendContactRel 
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int FriendId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: dknaack, what If i want one friend row to be associated with two contacts? If I were designing database, then ContactId1 would point to Contact table and ContactId2 would point to Contact table as well.

Comment: this is possible with my solution.

Comment: My solutions says... its not possible to have two rows with the same friend and same same contact is possible. you can have several friends to have the same contact and several contatcts to have same friends. Thats many to many

Comment: I could see how that might work. But this creates three database tables. I would think that I could use two tables. One that holds contacts, and one that holds Friends, where a Friend table row is composed of two distinct ContactId values (ContactId1 and ContactId2)