# Many to many relationship with JUNCTION TABLE in Entity Framework first code

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4.3

This is my first experience using ASP.NET MVC4 and ENTITY FRAMEWORK FIRST CODE.

I've got three tables. Just one of them is working as the JUCTION TABLE called TestObjectivesLink. The problem is when I use the command `Update-Database -Verbose` it creates a column reference in Objectives.

I have some doubts, I can't create the JUCTION TABLE because the table has not PK, and how can I do to retrieve the data. By example, how to retrieve the objectives from a test?

```
[Table("Objective")]
public class Objective
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
}

[Table("Test")]
public class Test
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TestId { get; set; }
}


[Table("TestObjectiveLink")]
public class TestObjectiveLink
{
    public Test Test { get; set; }
    public Objective Objective { get; set; }
    //public ICollection<Objective> Objectives { get; set; }
}

public class ContosoDb : DbContext
{
    public ContosoDb() : base("name=DefaultConnection") {}

    public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Objective> Objectives { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TestObjectiveLink> TestObjectiveLink { get; set; }
}
```

This is the result of my tables after a enter the command `Update-Database -Verbose`

[image]

How can I indicate to Entity which I'm trying to do?

Comment: For a one-to-many relationship you don't need a relationship table. You just need an `Objectives` collection in class `Test` and a `Test` reference in class `Objective`. What's the purpose of your third table?

Comment: Well, maybe I couldn't express my doubt as well. I really need a junction table. But I'm still receiving a reference Id column in Objective Table

Comment: I cannot believe that the model your are showing creates the DB schema you are showing. There must be something missing. Also, you cannot have an entity without key, it will throw an exception before any DB schema gets created at all.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve, but for a "normal" many-to-many relationship you don't need the relationship entity `TestObjectiveLink`, but instead two collections in the other entities. You can map the relationship table name and column names with Fluent API. Example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5994416/270591